# React-Native Local Notifications using Headless JS

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, local, headless

I am trying to send local notifications in the react native for android. By googling i saw that one way is to use Headless JS, but does anyone know how it can be achieved exactly? And I need local notifications everyday at a specific time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: Thanks a Ton .... It helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by using

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#scheduled-notifications

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#repeating-notifications

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
  date: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)) // in 60 secs
});
```

**Edit 1**

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    message: "My Notification Message",
    date: new Date(fireDate),
    repeatType: 'time',
    repeatTime: 3600000
  });
```

Comment: How can i get notification daily at 10 am ????

Comment: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#repeating-notifications 

`PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    message: "My Notification Message",
    date: new Date(fireDate),
    repeatType: 'time',
    repeatTime: 3600000
  });`

Comment: Where I have to place this code ??? In App.js ???? I have created the project using " react-native init <project_name " ....... And what does the " repeatTime " stands for ???

Comment: Bro you have to see documentation of npm  `react-native-push-notification` and config accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot .... Its too helpful